# Upgrading to 10.10 causes mountall error in Parallels

Tags: 10.10, boot, upgrade, parallels

I just recently upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 using the update manager tool.

After the upgrade, I was asked to reboot and it fails with

> An error occurred while mounting /media/psf
>   Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

Skipping gives me this:

[image]

Logging in with the command line prompt doesn't bring me to the UI, but stays in terminal mode. I would appreciate next steps to resolving this situation.

I am running Ubuntu on a Parallels 5 VM.

A reboot using recovery mode ends the same way but with this screen I also ran into a mention of mountall having an error, but I'm having trouble replicating the screen at the moment:

[image]

Comment: A reboot using recovery mode ends the same way but with this [screen](http://i52.tinypic.com/24gna07.jpg)

I also ran into a mention of mountall having an error, but I'm having trouble replicating the screen at the moment.

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1485251

Comment: thanks for the redirect, didn't really solve my problem but its a more appropriate thread to continue my research

Comment: I am having the same issue... Has any solution been found for this yet?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

“>”..Select the 'Virtual machine' menu item in parallels when your VM is running, select 
“>”'Reinstall Parallels Tools'....

Your solution only works if you can get the upgrade VM running in the first place.

If it can't mount /media/psf, then you're sunk. Your VM won't finish loading. And choosing "Reinstall Parallels Tools" will lead you to an empty pair of hands - i.e., it just won't work. You can't get to the actual VM because your Parallels tools are trying to load and crashing your loader's intentions. When Parallels drivers crash, your VM crashes.

Parallels forums advises that a "future update" will help 11.04 run. However, for many, the upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 on the Mac is a disaster. So, your old info is likely lost - unless you had the forethought to backup your /home folder and other stuff, like FireFox bookmarks, et al.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. Try uninstalling parallels tools from your VM. To do this select the 'Virtual machine' menu item in parallels when your VM is running, select 'Reinstall Parallels Tools'. When the ISO mounts run the install script and select the remove option rather than update. Restart your VM and install any new update in Ubuntu if they exits.

Now run the upgrade again and you are away. There should be no more installation issues, however the Parallels tools still do not support 11.04 yet so you will have to do without until Parallels get their act together!